# Wysiwyg making each word clickable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg

Ok. I have an editable div into which I can enter some text. However after entering I have 3 buttons: black, yellow and green.

What I want to be ble to do is to then click ie button "black" and then click each of the word which I have typed into the editable area. After clicking a word, that clicked word should have a div class='black' wrapped around it?

Also if the same word is clicked again I need to remove the wrapped div (so I can chamge the colour of the word,if I whish to do so?).

Furthermore I want the div to be deleted if I delete any words wrapped with a div.

Any help is appreciated?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome! When posting a question, please consider including relevant code (script, markup, styles) in the question to understand your problem and approach, and if possible make a http://jsfiddle.net working [demo](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/complete.html) of your approach. `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using jQuery? You need something like that:

```
function prepareDivContainer()
{
  // remove extra spaces
  var str = $("#editableDiv").text().replace(/[\s]+/g, ' ');

  // split the string by space into words
  var words = str.split(' ');

  // clear the content of the editable div
  $("#editableDiv").text('');

  // insert each word wrapped with a div
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
  {
    $("#editableDiv").append('<div id="word'+i+'">'+words[i]+'</div>');
  }
}
```

This function you call after the user has finished inserting text into the div. It will wrap all word into div.

So, now you can made these divs (words) clickable by binding to the click-event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#editableDiv div").live("click", function(){
    // do something with the clicked word (div), e.g. add or remove css classes
    // look here: http://api.jquery.com/category/css/
  });
});
```

Comment: The only tag on the question is `[jquery]`, so I think it's safe to assume so. `;)`

Comment: Hi Jared. I suppose that will get me half way :). I only need to add divs around the words which does not already have divs around them. Or the i will end up having words wrapped in several divs. And I need the div to be deleted if i delete the word (or many words) with them. But thanks for the idea. I guess if i could split each word by div wraps and then by spaces I could manage to do what I'm trying to do :)